# Redirection and reloading is not working with authentication implemented in Razor Class Library

Tags: .net, razor, blazor

I have implemented authentication in a RCL in Blazor project. When I click on Register link it is displaying Restration page (From RCL). When I click on submit it is creating user data in Aspnetuser table but when calling

```
RedirectManager.RedirectTo(
    "Account/RegisterConfirmation",
    new() { ["email"] = Input.Email, ["returnUrl"] = ReturnUrl });
```

It is throwing *IdentityRedirectManager can only be used during static rendering* and not navigating to RegisterConfirmation page exception.

```
Below is my code.
```

register.razor

```
public async Task RegisterUser(EditContext editContext)
     {
         var user = CreateUser();
    
         await UserStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
         var emailStore = GetEmailStore();
         await emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
         var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
    
         if (!result.Succeeded)
         {
             identityErrors = result.Errors;
             return;
         }
    
         Logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");
    
         var userId = await UserManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
         var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
         code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
         var callbackUrl = NavigationManager.GetUriWithQueryParameters(
             NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("Account/ConfirmEmail").AbsoluteUri,
             new Dictionary<string, object?> { ["userId"] = userId, ["code"] = code, ["returnUrl"] = ReturnUrl });
    
         await EmailSender.SendConfirmationLinkAsync(user, Input.Email, HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl));
    
         if (UserManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
         {
             RedirectManager.RedirectTo(
                 "Account/RegisterConfirmation",
                 new() { ["email"] = Input.Email, ["returnUrl"] = ReturnUrl });
         }
    
         await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
         RedirectManager.RedirectTo(ReturnUrl);
     }
```

RegisterConfirmation.razor

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    if (Email is null)
    {
        RedirectManager.RedirectTo("");
    }

    var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(Email);
    if (user is null)
    {
        HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
        statusMessage = "Error finding user for unspecified email";
    }
    else if (EmailSender is IdentityNoOpEmailSender)
    {
        // Once you add a real email sender, you should remove this code that lets you confirm the account
        var userId = await UserManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
        var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
        code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
        emailConfirmationLink = NavigationManager.GetUriWithQueryParameters(
            NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("Account/ConfirmEmail").AbsoluteUri,
            new Dictionary<string, object?> { ["userId"] = userId, ["code"] = code, ["returnUrl"] = ReturnUrl });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a `RedirectManager`? In Blazor you would normally use `NavigationManager`.

Comment: When i created Blazor project with authentication it gave this code.
Even when i am using Navigationmanager i am getting same issue.
From chat GPT:
Use NavigationManager when:

You need to navigate to a different page within the same Blazor application.
You want to handle client-side navigation.
Use RedirectManager when:

You want to perform a redirect to another page.
You need to include parameters as part of the redirected URL.

Comment: HI @Grandizer Not yet